# How can I place three block of contents in one line in a way that the middle block is always full width?

Tags: html, css

I have three blocks of content that I would like to place inline in a way that the middle block is always full width (fills 100% of the space between first block and the 3rd block).

How can I achieve this using just HTML and CSS?

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}
.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.two {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
.three {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='one'>One</div>
  <div class='two'>Two</div>
  <div class='three'>Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: define the width like 75%

Comment: Do you know the size of `one` and `three`, or will they be dynamic?

Comment: @Mathletics I don't think it would make any difference but let's assume all the widths are dynamic. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Approach 1**

  Set the parent element's `display` to `flex` and add `flex-grow: 1` to the middle element:

  ```css
  .row {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 1px;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .one {
      border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .two {
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .three {
      border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class='row'>
      <div class='one'>One</div>
      <div class='two'>Two</div>
      <div class='three'>Three</div>
  </div>
  ```

---

- **Approach 2**

  Set the `display` of the parent element to `table`, and the children element's `display` to `table-cell`. Then set the width of the middle element to `100%`.

  ```css
  .row {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .row > div {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .one {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .two {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .three {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class='row'>
      <div class='one'>One</div>
      <div class='two'>Two</div>
      <div class='three'>Three</div>
  </div>
  ```

---

- **Approach 3** (the middle element won't fill the remaining space, though)

  Float the first element to the left, float the third one to the right and use `text-align: center` on the parent element to center the middle one:

  ```css
  .row {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .one {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
  }
  .two {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .three {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='one'>One</div>
    <div class='two'>Two</div>
    <div class='three'>Three</div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks for the answer, the first approach seems to be working. I didnt know anything about "display:flex" till now! but your second approach doesn't quite work. The middle block needs to fill out the gap between two blocks

Comment: @Saeed There are 3 approaches in there now.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Awesome, Approach 2 is what I was exactly looking for. Thanks a lot!